# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] with angular-ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

my main index file has this in the head:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <!-- styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <!-- scripts -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

My script.js file has this:

```
    var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute'], ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

I'm getting an "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]" specifically related to the ui.bootstrap.  if i remove it as a dependency, i don't get the error, but i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.  any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject dependencies in a single array. Change it to

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```